# "Number of passed names did not match number of header fields in the file" Error while using read_excel in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, exception, header

Getting this exception while using read_excel function in pandas.

I am trying to fetch columns based on the column labels in the header. And getting this error. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

Here's the function:

```
pd.read_excel(myexcel.xlsx, sheet_name = 'sheet1', names = ['company name', 'service provided'], header = 1)
```

Getting the following error when I run it:

"Number of passed names did not match number of header fields in the file"

Comment: Header is 0 indexed, pass in header = 0 and drop the names kwarg.

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.read_excel(myexcel.xlsx, sheet_name = 'sheet1', usecols = ['company name', 'service provided'], header = 1)
```

Comment: This should solve the problem, see the help at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html